# How to remove Debian screen at system start?

Tags: grub2, plymouth

I have Ubuntu 12.04LTS on my Lenovo S205 laptop. Five days back, I was trying to install "mailutils" and "sendmail" for learning purpose. Since I installed this, I get a Debian screen when I start my laptop, where I have to select the OS I want to boot in. This screen doesn't show every time but about at least 2 out of 5 times. I tried uninstalling mailutils and sendmail, which I don't exactly are the reason for this screen.

I don't have any other OS on my laptop and hence, want to get rid of it. I am a fairly new user. So, a step-by-step help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The Debian image appears in the boot menu (when you select GRUB) or after you select the boot?

Comment: One of the two answers is right, but only if you make clear the problem.

Comment: Braiam this screen comes in the boot menu

Comment: Following Faron's comments has rendered my system unbootable. After the "Lenovo" screen when I power up my system, it gives me some hardware message and asks to select hardware and that's it... it doesn't go any further. Guess I should have waited for detailed discussion on this. Obviously... help!!

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth) - go down to 'Themes'

It basically says:

---

## Themes

As root run the next commands:

```
/usr/sbin/plymouth-set-default-theme --list
```

To display all installed themes.

```
/usr/sbin/plymouth-set-default-theme THEME
```

To set one theme, where THEME is one of listed in the previous command.

If you get the error "/usr/lib/plymouth/script.so does not exist", install plymouth-drm.

```
aptitude install plymouth-drm
```

And try again to set the theme.

## Apply changes

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is GRUB that you are dealing with.  If that is so, reinstall your GRUB would do the trick.

Two methods to choose from:

Method A:

Use your installation cd and start the system off from it as if you are installing a fresh Ubuntu.

Select the option from menu, "Rescue the broken system"

You will go through the cycle of series of questions which it would lead you to partition section. When you arrive to that section, escape the process. You then will see the menu and you should see "Install GRUB".

Re-install GRUB on your master HD (sda1)

Reboot

Method B:

```
   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   $ boot-repair
```