# Kubuntu's TTY resolution too low after installing nvidia-current

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, resolution, tty

After installing Kubuntu on a Notebook with GeForce Go 6100 graphics card, the tty's were working correctly, but the KDE desktop wouldn't display anything correctly. After installing the nVidia driver using `apt-get install nvidia-current` as root, the KDE desktop was displayed correctly. But now the TTY's have a very low resolution (the font is about 4x as big as it's supposed to be) and the flashing *kubuntu* Plymouth-animation was replaced by a text based animation looking like this:

```
Kubuntu 13.10
.  .  .  .  .
```

Where the dot's were changing it's color like on Ubuntu (not Kubuntu) bootup.

What happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try [changing the plymouth theme](http://askubuntu.com/questions/389147/how-to-remove-debian-screen-at-system-start/389152#389152). There is a guide [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/173221/178596) on changing tty.

Comment: Both don't have any effect. It's the used screen resolution, not the font size.

Comment: I guessed that, but I found it useful on a 1024x600 notebook... You could reinstalling` plymouth`, even though the problem is how it displays it... You might just need to configure it to use nvidia card properly...

Comment: And how would I do that if I might ask?

Comment: I ran that before and it didn't show any effect

Comment: Just noticed, I meant [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual#Configure) link :-s . There is also`nvidia-xconfig` - You might want to backup `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` first.

Comment: For the file you told me to backup didn't exist, `nvidia-xconfig` created it... Still no effect

Answer (score 0):

two things

First,

fix grub resolution:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Now, locate the line

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

and change it to this:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800 
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Next,

add framebuffer:

```
echo "echo FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

finally, update grub and initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

reboot for the changes to take effect

Comment: source: http://www.binarytides.com/ubuntu-fix-nvidia-graphics/

Comment: I have this same issue but I can't get the fix it work. After reboot the resolution is still 640x480. Also when I run `sudo update-initramfs-u` to get this error: `Warning: Not updating LILO; /etc/lilo.conf not found!`

Comment: @MichaelLindman This is for if you are using the grub2 bootloader. If you are using lilo, you may have to do something else. If you are using grub2 and somehow installed lilo but are not using lilo then you should probably uninstall lilo and then try again. It appears you installed lilo but have not put it to use yet  so that's what I would guess here. If you already uninstalled it, maybe try purging or re-installing, then purging lilo and then try to updtae the initramfs again.

Comment: I solved my issue with the TTY resolution by using the `xorg-edgers` ppa instead of the drivers downloaded from [nvidia.com](http://nvidia.com). Something in the driver configuration must not have been working properly to allow me to set a high resolution on the TTY, Thank you for the response though.